# How do I clear Apache Tomcat log?

Tags: java, tomcat

There's an error coming from JSP file that I have fixed it long ago but whenever I run my project, it keep remind me with it even thought those code no longer exist. When I go to my Apache Tomcat logs folder, it's empty. So I try clean Netbean cache but it still doesn't work. Where is those logs saved and how can I get rid of them?

Comment: Logs or compiled JSP  classes?

Comment: Errors appear in my Apache Tomcat Log output.

Comment: This means that offending classes are  somewhere on the classpath of your application. This has nothing to do with logging ( JSP files are converted to java code which is then compiled an executed.  Sources and compiled classes are well hidden somewhere in tomcat guts )

Comment: So is there a way for me to find them and clear them? Those error pointing to a few lines of my old code which I have delete them. Therefor, I think this is some kind of a history cache and somehow they keep diging and using those instead of focusing on my current one.